# Permissive vs Strict API

Tags: api-design, protobuf

This question is similar to [Permissive vs. Strict API Message validation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/385379/228019). One difference is that we're using Protobuf.

A colleague and I are discussing standard message types for names.

One possibility is:

```
message Name {
  string first_name = 1;
  string middle_name = 2;
  string last_name = 3;
}
```

Another possibility is:

```
message ShortName {
  string first_name = 1;
  string last_name = 2;
}

message LongName {
  string first_name = 1;
  string middle_name = 2;
  string last_name = 3;
}
```

The first version takes advantage of fields being optional by default in proto3. The second version makes it more clear what the API is really expecting.

I'm thinking https://www.flowmapp.com/blog/glossary-term/postels-law leans more towards the first version while `Don’t omit fields` in https://medium.com/epignosis-engineering/rest-api-development-tips-and-best-practices-part-2-d3ae4a13cbb7 somewhat leans towards the second version.

What are the pros and cons of either of these approaches?

Comment: Related:  https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: Thanks. I'm fully expecting new requirements to come up as we expand markets. That's another reason not to have overly specified definitions for the same semantics.

Comment: I think the point there is really to focus on why you need their name in the first place and what behaviours of the system it links to;   Instead of asking users for their name, you may prefer to ask them to enter different names depending on context - for example, their official/legal name may be different to their preferred colloquial name, which may be different to the name they wish to have displayed publicly, which may also be different to the name they wish to be used when you address them, etc.       In other words, consider focusing on the reason for the name, not the name itself.

Comment: The point of the question isn't the Name type itself even though the article you pointed to is helpful for that specific case (which involves health records in the US and UK for now and the near future). The point of the question are the pros and cons of Permissive and Strict APIs.